# How to aggregate rows from a large excel file

Tags: vba

I have a large excel file with lot of rows. I would like to sum these rows that have the same criteria (there are 4/5 columns of criteria and 6/7 columns of things to sum up).

- Is it possible to create a VBA to create that summing process?
- Is it possible to do it in another excel sheet linking to the main one without having to open the original excel file (since it takes a lot of time to open).

Comment: Couldn't a pivot table and Slicers do this for you?

Comment: I want to make it automatic since will have to do it on a monthly basis and there is a lot of rows that would be changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both, but it's probably easier to do a summation using the SumIfs function or a pivot table. However, if you are set on VBA, here's some code:

```
Sub SumNumber()
'Column F is data to sum
'Column B is year
'Column C is month

MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Columns("F"), Columns("B"), "2018", Columns("C"), "April")

End Sub
```

If you want to sum multiple columns, just duplicate the sumifs with a different initial range (not column F).

Example: Sumifs(Columns("F)...  + SumIfs(Columns("E")...

(Note this is practically identical is making a formula in a cell)

[Here is a file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12GNvRTdRXinMzLYls0lzjX-H3VYMT6nm/view?usp=sharing) that has some sample data with this macro. It also has a pivot table which would probably be a much better choice.

In answer to your other question, you can link from another sheet. You just need to use a file path reference, however this tends to break down as directories get renamed, security profiles change, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running SQL directly on the Excel workbook if using Excel for PC since it can connect to the Jet/ACE Engine (Windows .dll files). Then, run the well-known and used aggregate query.

Below assumes you have a worksheet named *OUTPUT*. Be sure to adjust `strSQL` for actual *Criteria* and *Col#* names and *SheetName*. If spaces and special characters are in column names, wrap `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` columns in square brackets `[]` or backticks ``` `` ```.

```
' ADO OBJECTS
Dim xlConn As Object, rs As Object
Dim icols As Long

Set xlConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' CURRENT WORKBOOK CONNECTION
xlConn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
              & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"

' AGGREGATE QUERY
strSQL = "SELECT Criteria1, Criteria2, Criteria3, Criteria4, " _
      & "   Sum(Col1) As TotalCol1, Sum(Col2) As TotalCol2, Sum(Col3) As TotalCol3," _
      & "   Sum(Col4) As TotalCol4, Sum(Col5) As TotalCol5, Sum(Col6) As TotalCol6" _
      & " FROM [SheetName$]" _
      & " GROUP BY Criteria1, Criteria2, Criteria3, Criteria4"

' OUTPUT RESULTS
rs.Open strSQL, xlConn

With Worksheets("OUTPUT")
    .Cells.Clear
    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For icols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        .Cells(1, icols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(icols).Name
    Next icols

    ' DATA ROWS
    .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End With    

rs.Close
xlConn.Close
```

Comment: That is great. Is there  a way to link to another excel file without opening it? I am using something like "Set DataFrom = Workbooks.Open(...)"

Comment: Also, when doing the select function, is there a way that we can put the column header in a row below the first row?

Comment: Sure you can specify any workbook in `DBQ=...` of connection string. Right now it uses current workbook. And this solution opens no Excel file. Queries are run in memory. And I am not sure what you mean in second question.

Comment: When doing a sql query, do you need to put the header of each column (Criteria 1, Criteria 2 ...) in row 1 of the excel worksheet so that it will recognize it? Let's say if my header are a bit lower (in row 5), how would I need to change the query?

Comment: Simply adjust where you want resultset placed at end. For column headers, change, `.Cells(1, icols + 1).Value` to needed row number such as 5: `.Cells(5, icols + 1).Value` For data rows, change `.Range("A2")` to leftmost cell of your output result such as "A6":  `.Range("A6")`.

Comment: Another quick question. If I use this syntax for the file I am linking to: Set DataFrom = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ ....) is it possible not to open the file?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. To output data to spreadsheet you need to actually open spreadsheet and write results. I thought this would run where data resides.